# im trying to substract 73 days from a temporary column from another temporary column

Tags: hive

Hivesql question: im trying to substract 73 days from the 'today' column value below is what i have,

temp table:

but it wont work. i got error msg "semanticexception[error]17980: operation is not supported. Table is not acid neither maprbjson.

How can get this done pls

this is what i tried

create temp table myvv(taday date, rdf date, alert date)

insert into(today)
select '2019-07-20;

update myvv set rdf = date_sub(today, 73)

column 'today' hold value date '2019-07-20' which ran successfully
Im expecting: to substract 73 days from the 'today' column value

Expected result : column rdf , result 2019-05-08

Answer (score 0):

This is the error you need to focus on

> Table is not acid neither maprbjson

So, you need to create a transactional table after making sure your hive version supports it and all properties are set correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Col1 datatype, Col2 datatype, ...) 
CLUSTERED BY (col1, ...) INTO num_buckets BUCKETS 
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES (transaction=true, ...);
```

After that you can try your `update` statement. Your statements are correct except transactional table. By default (your SQL) hive creates non-transactional  table which doesnt support update.